# How to know which Resource is being used when using SimPy's Simpy.events.AnyOf

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

I am using python 3.7 with SimPy 4. I have 4 `Resources` (say "First Level") with a capacity of 5 and each `Resource` has an associated `Resource` (say "Second Level") with a capacity of 1 (So, 4 "First Level" Resources and 4 "Second Level" Resources in total). When an agent arrives, it requests a `Resource` from any `Resource` of the "First Level", when it gets access to it then it requests the associated `Resource` of the "Second Level".

I am using `AnyOf` to choose any of the "First Level" Resources. It works but I need to know which Resource is chosen by which agent. How can I do that?

Here is a representation of what I am doing so far:

```py
from simpy.events import AnyOf, Event

num_FL_Resources = 4
capacity_FL_Resources = 5
FL_Resources = [simpy.Resource(env, capacity = capacity_FL_Resources ) for i in range(num_FL_Resources)]
events = [FirstLevelResource.request() for FirstLevelResource in FL_Resources]
yield Anyof(env, events)
```

**Note 1:** I didn't use `Store` or `FilterStore` in the "First Level" and randomly put the agent to one of the available `Store` because the agents are keep coming and all of the `Stores` might be in use. They need to queue up. Also, please let me know if there is a good way of using `Store` here.

**Note 2:** Resource.users gives me `<Request() object at 0x...>` so it isn't helpful.

**Note 3:**: I am using a nested dictionary for "First Level" and "Second Level" Resources like below. However, for convenience I didn't add my longer code here.

```py
{'Resource1': {'FirstLevel1': <simpy.resources.resource.Resource at 0x121f45690>,
               'SecondLevel1': <simpy.resources.resource.Resource at 0x121f45710>},
 'Resource2': {'FirstLevel2': <simpy.resources.resource.Resource at 0x121f457d0>,
               'SecondLevel2': <simpy.resources.resource.Resource at 0x121f458d0>},
 'Resource3': {'FirstLevel3': <simpy.resources.resource.Resource at 0x121f459d0>,
               'SecondLevel3': <simpy.resources.resource.Resource at 0x121f45a90>},
 'Resource4': {'FirstLevel4': <simpy.resources.resource.Resource at 0x121f47750>,
               'SecondLevel4': <simpy.resources.resource.Resource at 0x121f476d0>}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I did it with a store.  In the store I have groups of first level objects that have a common second level resource.  here is the code

```
"""
example of a two stage resource grab using a store and resouces

A agent will queue up to get a first level resource object 
and then use this object to get a second level rescource
However groups of the frist level resouce have one common second level resource
so there will also be a queue for the second level resource.

programer: Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy
import random

class FirstLevel():
    """
    A frist level object, a group of these objects will make a type of resource
    each object in the group will have the same second level resource
    """

    def __init__(self, env, groupId, secondLevel):
        self.env = env
        self.groupId = groupId
        self.secondLevel = secondLevel

def agent(env, agentId, firstLevelStore):
    """
    sims a agent/entity that will first grab a first level resource
    then a second level resource
    """

    print(f'agent {agentId} requesting from store with {len(firstLevelStore.items)} and queue {len(firstLevelStore.get_queue)}')
    
    # queue and get first level resouce
    firstLevel =  yield firstLevelStore.get() 
    print(f"agent {agentId} got first level resource {firstLevel.groupId} at {env.now}")

    # use the first level resource to queue and get the second level resource
    with firstLevel.secondLevel.request() as req:
        yield req
        print(f"agent {agentId} got second level resource {firstLevel.groupId} at {env.now}")
        yield env.timeout(random.randrange(3, 10))

    print(f"agent {agentId} done second level resource {firstLevel.groupId} at {env.now}")
    
    # put the first level resource back into the store
    yield firstLevelStore.put(firstLevel) 
    print(f"agent {agentId} done first level resource {firstLevel.groupId} at {env.now}")

def agentGen(env, firstLevelStore):
    """
    creates a sequence of agents
    """

    id = 1
    while True:
        yield env.timeout(random.randrange(1, 2))
        print(f"agent {id} arrives {env.now}")
        env.process(agent(env,id, firstLevelStore))
        id += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("start")

    num_FL_Resources = 4        # number of first level groups/pools
    capacity_FL_Resources = 5   # number of first level in each group/pool

    env = simpy.Environment()

    # store of all first level, all mixed togethers
    store = simpy.Store(env, capacity=(num_FL_Resources * capacity_FL_Resources))

    for groupId in range(num_FL_Resources):
        # create the second level resource for each group os first level resources
        secondLevel = simpy.Resource(env,1)
        for cap in range(capacity_FL_Resources):
            # create the individual first level objects for the group
            firstLevel = FirstLevel(env,groupId,secondLevel)
            store.items.append(firstLevel)

    env.process(agentGen(env, store))
    env.run(200)

    print("done")
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough! You spent you valuable time and wrote a great program. That also helped me to correct my misunderstanding of request() as well.